# Sharepoint WebPart DataSource

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, datasource

I'm learning how to develop webparts in SharePoint 2010.

What I'm having difficulty finding is how to allow the user to change the DataSource of the WebPart in the UI. I want to allow them to pick a list from the site, preferably of a specific type but one thing at a time.

Is there a specific control to do this or are you just supposed to expose a property of the webpart so the user can alter it?

There must be information on this out there but I'm having trouble finding it.
Does anybody have any good links on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Craig,

Using Web Part Property you can change DataSource from Edit mode and save it.

For custom webpart property click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Let me know if u have any query.

Comment: Yeah I looked at Custom Properties. Am I right when I say that a DropDown property can only be populated from an enum? I looked at creating a custom ToolPart and putting a DropDown on there, surely this can't be the right way of doing it. Why wouldn't you be able to have a dynamically populated Webpart Property DropDown?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is the Content Query Web Part you are looking for.

This sounds like a great place to start reading:
*"How to: Customize the SharePoint Content By Query Web Part by Using Custom Properties (ECM)"*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx

Good luck!